# My eclipse IDE failing to detect changed files in Git perspective?

Tags: eclipse, git

Hi I have Eclipse Mars Installed, I have imported git repository (Having PHP code inside). Open perspective is "Git". `Once I open eclipse, it says no repository has been selected. I click on repository, it shows progress bar (I guess git status might be running at background). Then it detects the changes that I made last time before closing the Eclipse. But since this point of time no any further file changes are getting detected by eclipse unless & until I restart it` & follow the steps as mentioned above. Is there any refresh button that eclipse has in git perspective ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the below screenshot which has refresh button in the git perspective, hope you are in this view.
[image: Here is the refresh in the git perspective]

Comment: Thank you Madhu V Rao for the help !!! Instead of down-vote :) Solution worked for me. One correction "Refresh" in "Git Staging" window at botton worked for me instead of "Git Repositories" window, I don't know whats the issue.